# Find DOM elements from values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, selector

I have a potential big list of id's, in this example: "1, 2, 4"

How can I loop through all rows inside a table and add a class to the element inside where the row is being matched with the class from the array? (using jQuery/javascript)

So this table:

```
<table>
   <tr class="row-1">
      <td><span class="foo">1</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-2">
      <td><span class="foo">2</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-3">
      <td><span class="foo">3</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-4">
      <td><span class="foo">4</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-5">
      <td><span class="foo">5</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Looks like this afterwards:

```
<table>
   <tr class="row-1">
      <td><span class="foo bar">1</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-2">
      <td><span class="foo bar">2</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-3">
      <td><span class="foo">3</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-4">
      <td><span class="foo bar">4</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-5">
      <td><span class="foo">5</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: All the answers use arrays rather than a string. You can convert your string to an array with `var myarray = mystring.Split(',');` (remove spaces first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var array = [1,2,4]; // etc...
$(array.map(function(i) {return ".row-" + i;}).join(',')).addClass('bar');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqewj7nc/)

In es6:

```
const array = [1,2,4]; // etc...
$(array.map(i => `.row-${i}`).join(',')).addClass('bar');
```

[Fiddle(es6)](https://jsfiddle.net/77mag5ep/1)

**edit** You can also use directly [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), i.e. (es6)

```
$(`.row-${array.reduce((a, b) => `${a},.row-${b}`)}`).addClass('bar');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
var ids = [1,2,4];

$( "tr[class^='row']" ).each( function(){
  var index = parseInt( $(this)[0].className.split("-")[1], 10 );
  
  if( ids.indexOf( index ) != -1 )
  {
    $(this).addClass("bar");
  }
});
```

```css
.bar
{
   color :red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr class="row-1">
      <td><span class="foo">1</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-2">
      <td><span class="foo">2</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-3">
      <td><span class="foo">3</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-4">
      <td><span class="foo">4</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-5">
      <td><span class="foo">5</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("tr[class*='row'] td span").addClass('foo')
```

Comment: Care for any additional explanation (like why choosing `*=` in the attribute selector)?